# 'Provided' dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have `build.gradle` in front of me and there are some dependencies declared as `provided` but in [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N105A1) I do not see this dependency scope.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    ....

    provided 'backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1'
    provided 'org.javolution:javolution:5.5.1@jar
    ....
}
```

Is this provided by a plugin? If so how do I found out which plugin this belongs to?

What is the difference between `provided` and `runtime` dependency scope in Gradle?

Comment: Do you have a configuration named `provided`?

Comment: I think I do not understand what kind of configuration you mean.

Comment: I mean an entry called `provided` in `configurations` block. Could you please paste the entire `build.gradle` script?

Comment: I use the [gradle-extra-configurations-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin) for this feature. There are similar plugins, like [propsdeps](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin), as well.

Comment: In the Maven world, the "provided" scope means a library that needs to be available in order to compile the project but which should not be exported as a transitive dependency or included in the final packaged archive (e.g. WAR file) because it will be "provided" in some other way by the target environment.  The classic example is web applications - you need the servlet API dependency at compile time but you don't want it in your final WAR because the web server will provide it on a parent classloader.

Comment: @Opal you are right there is provided in configurations. I didn't know you can define your own dependency scope.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> What is `provided` scope?

Suppose that a `jar` is needed to compile your code, but the jar is present in the production environment library collection. Then you don't need to package the jar with your project archives. To support this requirement, Maven has a scope named `provided`. If you declare any jar dependency as `provided`, then this jar will be present in your classpath during compilation but will not be packaged with your project archive.

`provided` scope is very useful, particularly in web applications. For example, `servlet-api.jar` is needed to be present in your classpath to compile your project, but you don't need this to package `servlet-api.jar` file with your `war`. With `provided` scope one can achieve this requirement.

There is no Scope defined in Gradle `java` plugin named `provided`. Also not in `war` or `android` plugins. If you want to use `provided` scope in your project, then you have to define it in your `build.gradle` file. Following is the code snippet to declare `provided` scope in gradle:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
}
```

Now, your second question:

> What is the difference between provided and runtime dependency scope in Gradle?

To answer this question first I will define `compile` dependency. `compile` dependencies are dependencies, those are necessary to compile your code. Now imagine that if your code uses a library named `X` then you must declare `X` as your compile-time dependency. Also imagine that `X` uses another library `Y` internally, and you declared `Y` as your runtime dependency.

During compilation, Gradle will add `X` into your classpath but will not add `Y`. Since, `Y` is not required for compilation. But it will package both `X` and `Y` with your project archive since both `X` and `Y` are necessary to run your project archive in the production environment. Generally, all the dependencies needed in the production environment are known as `runtime` dependency.

In Gradle official [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html), it says that `runtime` dependency are "***the dependencies required by the production classes at runtime. By default, also includes the compile time dependencies.***".

Now, if you've read this far, then you already know that `provided` is a `compile` dependency that we don't want to be present in the `runtime` dependency (basically, we don't want it to package with the project archive).

Following is an illustration of `provided` and `runtime` scope. Here, `compile` refers to the dependencies that are required to compile the project and `non-compile` refers to the dependencies that are not required for project compilation.

[image]

Comment: The `compileOnly` configuration is the closest option to mavens "provided" scope, but it is not a true "only at compile time" configuration. For instance, project Lombok classes are needed during the compile, but are **never** needed at runtime, should **never** be provided at runtime, and should **never** be packaged. This is different than the servlet dependencies that are needed during compile and runtime, but not needed during packaging because they are provided by the environment. Neither Maven nor Gradle have built in distinctions between true "compile only" and "compile provided".

Comment: the `runtime` configuration is deprecated, use `runtimeOnly` instead

Comment: Here Gradle themselves write that `runtime` should be replaced by `runtimeOnly` and `provided` should be replaced by `compileOnly` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:migrating_deps

Comment: If you're using the war plugin you also get 'providedCompile', https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:migrating_deps

Answer (score 22):

As from Gradle 2.12, you can use the `compileOnly` option.

See

https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies

Comment: As from Gradle 6.7 there is also `compileOnlyApi` dependency:
https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html#new-dependency-management-features

Comment: Tried this, this yields <scope>compile</scope>, not cool

Answer (score 12):

For further clarification, as of the latest version, Gradle 5.5 has `compileOnly` (same as `provided`) and `runtimeOnly` options.  The new default "compile and runtime" option is `implementation`.

Comment: IIUC "compileOnly" does not provide the lib for compiling and running tests. This is a pity.

Comment: @fml2 how so?  can't you use testCompileOnly <dependency> / testImplementation <dependency> etc.

Comment: Yes, I can. But it would be more convenient IMO if, by including a lib via `compileOnly`, I automatically could use it in the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer as per the latest gradle versions.

From gradle's official documentation at below link:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html

> ***Deprecations***
>
> **Dependencies should no longer be declared using the compile and runtime configurations. The usage of the compile and runtime
> configurations in the Java ecosystem plugins has been discouraged
> since Gradle 3.4.**
>
> **The implementation, api, compileOnly and runtimeOnly configurations should be used to declare dependencies and the compileClasspath and
> runtimeClasspath configurations to resolve dependencies.**

More so, the compile dependency configuration has been removed in the recently released Gradle 7.0 version.

If you try to use compile in your Gradle 3.4+ project you’ll get a warning like this:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use ‘–warning-mode all’ to show the
> individual deprecation warnings.

You should always use implementation rather than compile for dependencies, and use runtimeOnly instead of runtime.

**War plugin**

> **The War plugin extends the Java plugin to add support for assembling web application WAR files. It disables the default JAR archive
> generation of the Java plugin and adds a default WAR archive task.**

The War plugin adds two dependency configurations:

1. providedCompile
2. providedRuntime

Adding an entry to providedCompile or providedRuntime will cause that dependency to be excluded from the war file.

1. Use providedCompile if you have source that relies on some classes
   for compiling.
2. Use providedRuntime if you use it for testing and not
   compiling.

**Example:**

```
providedCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.1.6.RELEASE'
```

The above JAR and its transitive dependency will only be available at compile time but it will not be available at runtime. It means, those JAR will not be included in war archive.