# Add dependencies in "Provided" scope for Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA provides an option to `Add dependencies in "Provided" scope to classpath` for Maven project, so I can run a Spark application in Intellij IDEA directly with the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My question is, how about Gradle's `complieOnly` dependencies? How can I enable similar setting in IDEA?

```
compileOnly 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Provided' dependency in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731084/provided-dependency-in-gradle)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam There is no Scope defined in Gradle java plugin named provided

Comment: Gradle uses `compileOnly` scope instead of the `provided`. What action do you mean is missing in IDE?

Comment: I want to find the alternative option to add `complieOnly` dependencies to classpath in IDEA.

Comment: Please file a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) describing how you would like it to work (describe the scenario and how you would use this action).